# web service return not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, weather

How can I display `GetCityForeCastByZip`

I am using http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx .

I get this error message:

> **Cannot implicitly convert type 'Weather.WeatherService.ForecastReturn' to 'Weather.WeatherService.WeatherReturn'**

```
WeatherService.WeatherReturn res = client.GetCityForecastByZIP();
```

Comment: Can you post entire error message?  It should say something like cannot implicitly convert "type X to type Y"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message indicates you are trying to assign a ForcastReturn type to a WeatherReturn type.  If you mouse over GetCityForecastByZIP you'll see it's return type is.

Based on your error message, this:

```
WeatherService.WeatherReturn result2 = client.GetCityForecastByZIP(txtZip.Text);
```

Should likely be this instead:

```
WeatherService.ForecastReturn result2 = client.GetCityForecastByZIP(txtZip.Text);
```

Comment: ForecastResult is an array of Forecast objects.  If you right click ForecastResult or highlight and hit F12, it'll go to it's definition and show you its type is `Forecast[]`.  You can view definition for Forecast and see what properties it has.  You could use a `foreach` loop and append strings from a property of each Forecast object.  Sounds like you're struggeling through the basics.  Some C# tutorials or book that covers the basics would probably be a good start.